# Why is double my half-equivalence point not equal to my equivalence point?

Tags: titration

[image]

Tris pKA = 8, therefore at pH = 8, the volume is 4.5mL. However the equivalence point simply can't be at 9mL, looking at this graph. It should be between approximately 9.5 and 10.5, no?

Comment: You were titrating diluted [tris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tris)?

Comment: Yes, 100mL of 0.1M tris.

Comment: It's rather weak base and conc. was low so this equiv. point simple is only slightly visible.

Comment: But how do I determine the actual value?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28054/calculating-ph-for-titration-of-weak-base-with-strong-acid